# How to separate UI properties and Data-model properties in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am starting to develop some more advanced UI for controlling some rows of a table where each row corresponds to an object in my model list.  There is a good amount of "extra" UI related properties that need to be associated with each object.

For example, lets say I am iterating through a list of User objects like this:

```
{
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Smith",
    "email" "jsmith@domain.com"
}
```

This is a simple object to display on the page, but there is a bunch of other UI related logic that is associated with this object.  For example, there is a search input on each row allowing the user to search for files related to the given user. I use some properties like `user.isSearching`, `user.Search.results`, `user.Search.isLoading`, etc.  These "extra" properties are needed to successfully display the UI I want, but they are NOT supposed to be apart of the data model, so when I try to POST the user back to the server, they all now have these extra properties on them.

Is there a standard way to separate the object properties that should be passed between client/server with the properties used solely to manage to UI flow?

Comment: My current "solution" is to just add all UI related properties onto a single object on the User. So I would create `user.UI.isSearching` and `user.UI.Search = {}`, etc. Then when I post, I can just `delete user['UI']`.. that works, but just doesn't seem like the best way

Comment: My suggestion would be to not have UI properties on objects that are to be communicated with the server at all. Instead keep the UI properties on the container that displays that object, and let the container have a reference to the object it will display.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "container"?

Comment: By container I meant the DOM element(s) that is displaying the object.